# How read Helm values files in NodeJS on RedHat Openshift?

Tags: node.js, kubernetes, openshift, kubernetes-helm

I created NodeJS application:

```
const http = require('http');
const Route =require('./route.js');
//Log
const logger = require('./logger.js');

//Server
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const port= process.env.PORT || 8080;
server = http.createServer(app)

app.use(express.json());
const password= process.env.PASS || "1234";

//endpoint
app.use(Route)

app.listen(port, ()=>{
  logger.info(`App started on port ${port}`)
})
```

This application will be deployed as container on RedHat Openshift and instead process.env. I have to use values from Helm Files.

I know that there are a special packages to read yaml files, but I not sure if it is required when we use Openshift. Is it?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Leave your code unmodified.  You can run it normally in a local development environment

```bash
export PASS=passw0rd
npm run dev
```

When you package it in a container, you can similarly supply an environment variable when you run it for local testing

```bash
docker run -d -e PASS=passw0rd your-image
```

In Kubernetes, you'd pass this in a container spec's `env:` block.  If you deploy this via a Helm chart, then you can substitute in its values at this point.

```yaml
# charts/myapp/templates/deployment.yaml
env:
  - name: PASS
    value: {{ .Values.password }}
```

```yaml
# dev-values.yaml
password: passw0rd
```

```bash
helm install . myapp -f dev-values.yaml
```

It can be a good practice to also use a Kubernetes Secret to pass the value along, but this provides minimal additional security.